# Smooth anchor links active element wrong when the content is too short on the first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am having problem with smooth anchor link, where there is only few content in the first section and second section is visible in the viewport, the active state shows to the second anchor.

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moviecrew/k4o275Lh/17/

try increasing the result page height and decreasing.

is there any way I can make the first item active when there is less content in the first section?

```
function initAnchors() {
  new SmoothScroll({
    anchorLinks: 'a.smooth-scroll[href^="#"]:not([href="#"])',
    // extraOffset: 185,
    extraOffset: 209,
    // extraOffset: 313,
    activeClasses: 'parent',
    anchorActiveClass: 'active',
    wheelBehavior: 'none'
  });
}
```

This is where the page is initialized.

Comment: this is unclear...

Comment: @MisterJojo when you make the page long so both content are visible on the same page, https://i.imgur.com/C9mu1iK.png like this, notice the second nav item is active. I don't need that. I need the first item active all the time at first

Comment: @MisterJojo  so you are suggesting there’s no way we can alter the behavior to have it something I described?

Comment: I change my mind: see answer below

Answer (score 0):

you can use **css** `min-height:100%:`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('header a').forEach(ha=>{
  ha.onclick=e=>{
    document.querySelector('header li.active').classList.remove('active')
    e.target.closest('li').classList.add('active')
  }
})
```

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;padding: 0; 
}
.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  background: #666;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
}
.nav li.active a,
.nav li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  border-bottom-color: #f0f;
}
/*  .subcontent {  padding-top: 40px;  } */ 
html { height:100%;  }
body { display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column; margin: 0;padding: 0;  }
  /*  header {  } */
main { flex-grow:1; overflow: auto; scroll-behavior: smooth;  }

.subcontent { min-height:100%; }
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a class="nav-tab-link smooth-scroll" href="#planBenefits">Plan Benefits</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-tab-link smooth-scroll" href="#supportDocuments">Support Documents</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
  <div id="planBenefits"  class="subcontent">
    <h1 class="push-bot-3 text-capitalize"><strong>Plan benefits</strong></h1>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="supportDocuments"  class="subcontent">
    <h1 class="push-bot-3 text-capitalize"><strong>Supports</strong></h1>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[edit] **other solution:**  *(just for the last subcontent)*

```js
document.querySelectorAll('header a').forEach(ha=>{
  ha.onclick=e=>{
    document.querySelector('header li.active').classList.remove('active')
    e.target.closest('li').classList.add('active')
  }
})
```

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;padding: 0; 
}
.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  background: #666;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
}
.nav li.active a,
.nav li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  border-bottom-color: #f0f;
}
/*  .subcontent {  padding-top: 40px;  } */ 
html { height:100%;  }
body { display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column; margin: 0;padding: 0;  }
  /*  header {  } */
main { flex-grow:1; overflow: auto; scroll-behavior: smooth;  }

main div.subcontent:last-child { min-height:100vh; }
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a class="nav-tab-link smooth-scroll" href="#planBenefits">Plan Benefits</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-tab-link smooth-scroll" href="#supportDocuments">Support Documents</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
  <div id="planBenefits"  class="subcontent">
    <h1 class="push-bot-3 text-capitalize"><strong>Plan benefits</strong></h1>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="supportDocuments"  class="subcontent">
    <h1 class="push-bot-3 text-capitalize"><strong>Supports</strong></h1>
    <p class="push-bot-2">Your plan is designed to help you create wealth, protect your wealth and transfer it to your beneficiaries in a tax efficient way. The actual long-term costs and benefits of your plan will vary from the original projection when underlying long-term assumptions such as tax rates, tax laws and interest rates change.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that won’t work since both the content should be visible. If I wanted to show only 1 content in a page, I could have used `height: 100vh` or similar to .subcontent and it could work perfectly. But thank you

Comment: @Lucian in this case use it just for the last one... `main div.subcontent:last-child { min-height:100vh; }`  _see my new added answer in my original post_